# require() not working inside module.exports

Tags: node.js, express

I've been playing with nodejs for a few months now but from last night it stated acting funny.

It's such a stupid problem that is better explained with an example.

This is my code:

FILE-A:

```
var Q = require('q');
var user = require('../p/user');

module.exports = {
    test: function() {
         console.log("*****************************************");
         console.log(user);
         console.log(require('../p/user'));
         console.log("*****************************************");
    }
};
```

and FILE-B:

```
var fileA = require('../fileA');
var Q = require('q');
fileA.test();
```

Very simple! The problem is that "user" imported into FILE-A is empty! This is the output:

```
*****************************************
{}
{ get: [Function],
update: [Function],
getProfilePicture: [Function] }
*****************************************
```

As you can see if I call directly require() in the code, everything is fine!

I feel stupid cause obviously is my fault but I cannot find a solution. do you have any idea of what can be causing this problem?

Thanks a lot!

UPDATE: this is the ../p/user file

```
/************************************
 *
 ***********************************/
 var Q = require('q');
 var cassandra = require('../../db/cassandra');
 var dateManager = require('../../commons/DateManager');

 var db = "test";
 var table = "user";

 module.exports = { 
       ...          
 };
```

Comment: show your user.js file. May it initialized after first call?

Comment: Hope this helps, I cannot see anything wrong! `/************************************
 *
 *
**********************************/
var Q = require('q');
var cassandra = require('../../db/cassandra');
var dateManager = require('../../commons/DateManager');

var db = "test";
var table = "user";

module.exports = { 
}; `

Comment: Bizarre. Could you throw in a `console.log(user);` just after the `var user = require('../p/user');` in fileA?

Answer (score 0):

Solved....but you are not going to like it, I just reinstalled nodejs and everything is fine now! (same version - v4)

I'm very upset, this is not the way I like to deal with problems and it's seriously shaking my confidence in nodejs. On the other hand, it's such a basic/common scenario that I'm keen on saying it was my fault!

Sorry for the non-solution!